# IntelliJ Idea не видит метода в классе

Tags: java, intellij-idea, selenium-webdriver

Пытаюсь сделать скриншот в тесте. Использую класс `FileUtils.copyFile`. Почему то не импортируется библиотека эта:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
```

В чем может быть дело?

[image: ...]

Comment: Вероятно, надо добавить эту библиотеку в проект. Какая система сборки используется, gradle, maven, ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да не было нужной зависимости в POM файле)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```